# spark mllib in als, how to set the max rating to the ALS model?

Tags: apache-spark, rating

I used the spark's ALS to test the data of  movielens. 
when the put data is like that

```
 uid,pid,rating.  
 1,1,2
 1,2,4
```

the max rating is 5.

so the data i wish is      `1,3,x   ,x<=5;`
but the result is          `1,3,8  or  1,3,9.`

so , I have no idea what I can do.please help me.  How to set the max rating to the model of ALS.

Comment: can you share what have you done so far ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ALS recommender has no way of knowing that you expect the ratings to fit into a specific range. If you want that to be the case, you'll need to implement that yourself, in a layer on top of what Spark is doing for you.

Note that adjusting the hyperparameters can reduce this effect; try increasing the rank a bit, for example.